# Как закрыть файловый поток после возврата его в теле http-ответа?

Tags: c#, потоки-данных, память, asp.net-web-api, filestream

### КОД

Есть вот такой код для скачивания файла:

**Контроллер FilesController**

```
public FilesController(IFileService fileService)
{
    this.fileService = fileService;
}

[HttpGet, Route("~/api/files/{id:int}/content")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetFileContent()
{
    var fileId = Convert.ToInt32(RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"]);
    var fileStream = fileService.GetFileContent(fileId);            

    var httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Content = new StreamContent(fileStream),
    };
    httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");

    return httpResponseMessage;
}
```

**Сервис FileService**

```
public FileStream GetFileContent(int fileId)
{          

    ...
    var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(sourceFileName);
    
    return fileStream ;
}
```

---

### ВОПРОС

Так как тут идет работа с разделяемым ресурсом - файл, то и поток `fileStream` необходимо закрыть вручную, как я понимаю. Но я не могу этого сделать, ведь я его и отсылаю в теле ответа. Нужно ли все таки как-то закрывать поток в подобной ситуации?

Comment: Ну вероятнее, его должен закрыть тот кому это ответ с потоком достанется, ведь он будет с нем работать.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов экшен GetFileContent() является пользователем этого потока. Но он не может его закрыть ведь он его возвращает.

Comment: Вам в данном случае не стоит самому закрывать поток, это сделает тот, кто им пользуется, или GC сам вызовет нужный финализатор при уничтожении ссылки на поток.

Comment: В этом случае вы все равно не должны трогать поток, его автоматом должен закрыть стек. Вероятно просто в С# я не силён.

Comment: @tym32167 "кто им пользуется". Ты хочешь сказать, что middleware/iis закроет поток? Просто я не совсем понимаю что происходит на этих уровнях с потоком.

Comment: @adamshakhabov вы поток отдали в `StreamContent`, `StreamContent` поместили в `HttpResponseMessage`, `HttpResponseMessage` отправили во фреймворк на десериализпцию. Я подозреваю, что когда `HttpResponseMessage` будет десериализован и станет ненужным, будет вызван его `Dispose()`, который по цепочке вызовов дойдет до закрытия потока. Но даже если этого не случится, то у потока должен быть финализатор, который будет вызван сборщиком мусора и также закроет поток.

Comment: @adamshakhabov [вот dispose() у HttpResponseMessage](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpResponseMessage.cs#L212), [а вот он у StreamContent](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/StreamContent.cs#L73) - вы видите, что у обоих вложенные ресурсы также диспозятся. То есть когда фреймворк захочет диспозить HttpResponseMessage, тогда же по цепочке вызовов закроется ваш поток.

Comment: @adamshakhabov `отправили во фреймворк на десериализпцию` читать как => `отправили во фреймворк на сериализпцию`. Что то сплю я